# VLAN trunking on same interface only pingable from hosts on its VLAN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vlan

I having the same problem.

I created a couple of VLAN's on my router, properly configured my zyxel layer 2 switch.

the entire network works as expected except one thing.

I created a virtual interface in ubuntu 14.04 server (eth0.7 10.1.7.199) on top of eth0 (10.1.10.10).

clients on vlan 7 can access the ubuntu 14.04 server only using the ip on eth0.7 (10.1.17.199)

clients on vlan 1 can access the ubuntu 14.04 server only using the ip on eth0 (10.1.10.21)

I've tried enabling log_martians and rp_filter and clients started to be able to just ping both interfaces on the ubuntu server but nothing else.

Wondering how can I properly configure a virtual interface on a seperate vlan connected to a trunked port.

I've follow the following post but only ping started working from ether vlan to either interface's IP.

[VLAN trunking on interface only pingable from hosts on its VLAN](https://superuser.com/questions/902865/vlan-trunking-on-interface-only-pingable-from-hosts-on-its-vlan)

Comment: What do you mean by only using x.x.x.x IP? One VLAN cannot jump to another without a router somewhere so traffic should be leaving the server and then come back.

Comment: There is a router in place. I have setup 7 vlans in the router with two layer 2 switches. All vlans can communicate between each other so the router and the switches are doing their job correctly. Problem is with one server. The physical interface eth0 grabs an ip just fine from the default vlan (1) and I've added a virtual interface (sudo vconfig add eth0.7) that when I bring this interface up the clients on vlan 7 can only reach the server using the ip on eth0.7 but no from the ip that eth0 has. if I turn eth0.7 down then everything works again.